# Connector fails when schema registry's master changes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

My source connector throws
`Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Error while forwarding register schema request to the master; error code: 50003`

or
`Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Master not known`

I found this happened
when schema registry's master changes and I have two replicas of schema-registry, under the same service on k8s.

The top exception is `org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler`

How to increase the tolerance so the connector can retry more times until the new master is elected?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have two replicas doesn't mean they know about each other.

See how to fix this - https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/issues/375

---

Regarding the error handler, you give timeouts. Example from the docs.

```
# retry for at most 10 minutes times waiting up to 30 seconds between consecutive failures
errors.retry.timeout=600000
errors.retry.delay.max.ms=30000
```